# How to split strings and store into a hashmap of strings in java

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to split below string

> G04:AMPARAMS|DCode=50|XSize=66mil|YSize=66mil|CornerRadius=0mil|HoleSize=0mil|Usage=FLASHONLY|Rotation=0.000|XOffset=0mil|YOffset=0mil|HoleType=Round|Shape=Octagon|*

I was first spliting the code from `'|'` pipe sign then spliting again from `'='` equal sign but problem i am facing here is that how to store the value in hashmap as they are in a loop so i can't store it in a hashmap. Any Possible solution would be appricated.

```
String[] temp=line.split("\\|");
for(String p:temp){
    HashMap<String,String>attributes=new HashMap<String,String>();
    String[] key =p.split("\\=");

    for(String tmp:key){
    //System.out.println(tmp);
    attributes.put();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like what you need is:

```
String[] temp = line.split("\\|");
Map<String,String> attributes = new HashMap<String,String>();
for (String p : temp) {
    String[] key = p.split("\\=");
    if (key.length == 2) {
        attributes.put(key[0],key[1]);
    }
}
```

Note that you should create a single `HashMap` outside the loop, since you want to store all the key-value pairs in the same `HashMap`.

Answer (score 4):

**No Streams:**

```
public static Map<String, String> split(String str) {
    final Pattern sep = Pattern.compile("\\s*\\|\\s*");
    final Pattern eqSep = Pattern.compile("(?<key>[^=\\s]+)\\s*=\\s*(?<value>[^=]+)");

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (String part : sep.split(str)) {
        Matcher matcher = eqSep.matcher(part);

        if (matcher.matches())
            map.put(matcher.group("key"), matcher.group("value"));
    }

    return map;
}
```

**With Streams:**

```
public static Map<String, String> split(String str) {
    final Pattern sep = Pattern.compile("\\s*\\|\\s*");
    final Pattern eqSep = Pattern.compile("(?<key>[^=\\s]+)\\s*=\\s*(?<value>[^=]+)");

    return sep.splitAsStream(str)
              .map(eqSep::matcher)
              .filter(Matcher::matches)
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(matcher -> matcher.group("key"), matcher -> matcher.group("value")));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is easier done via streams:

```
Arrays.stream(input.split("\\|"))
      .map(s -> s.split("="))
      .filter(a -> a.length == 2)
      .collect(toMap(a -> a[0], a -> a[1], (l, r) -> r, HashMap::new));
```

- `Arrays.stream` create a `Stream<String>` which we can then further refine our query via several [built-in stream API methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html).
- `map` splits each string on "=" therefore returns a `Stream<String[]>`
- `filter` retains the array elements that have exactly two elements
- finally, we supply a `toMap` collector to the `collect` method to build the `Map<String, String>`

Comment: It may be worth adding that the OP specifically asked for a HashMap, but `toMap` creates a map of unspecified nature.

Comment: to avoid creating an intermediate array it is better to use `Pattern.compile.splitAsStream` which returns stream directly: `Pattern.complile("\\|").splitAsStream(input)`